Cross platform (ios/android/web) google auth
I'm mostly backend person. Lately I wanted to create crossplatform app (ios/android/web).
I found that react native + expo can easily help me solving my problems. The problem that I didn't find answer to is how to implement auth there with my requirements:

I want single code base for ios/android/web.
I want Google sign in, NOT login+password.

===
My journey so far:

I started with firebase, and I was able to implement it with react-native package, and then using signInWithGoogleCred. The problem is that expo google auth is native package, which, I guess, prohibits me from using it on the web. Another thing that I don't want to use it with firebase + I don't want to be coupled to the raw google tokens.
Then I found such thing called "clerk", and it seemed to have some integration guide with expo, but only for login+password flow. I still was able to find the blog article about how to integrate with Google in clerk via WebBrowser, but it does not actually work when I try run it for browser: WebBrowser.warmUpAsync is not available on web, are you sure you've linked all the native dependencies properly. For Expo Go it also does not work, because  is using raw text inside: Text strings must be rendered within a <Text> component. So it seems clerk is not mature enough for mobile yet.

Now I'm a bit lost, how in general cross platform apps are doing OAuth authorization, like what if I have my custom oauth flow (OpenIddict for example) that needs browser? What is the best way for 2024 to authorize ios/androi/web with Google and be able to easily validate the token on some backend, let's say nestjs, or dotnet.

I'm thinking, maybe I want too much? I think it is impossible to cover web as well. But at least ios/andoid with 1 code base and google auth without firebase but with some other auth provider (I want to omit raw Google auth token validation)
